# Use cURL to call API in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following codes, however, it does not return anything-a blank page. But if I plug in the right parameters and place the entire link on web browser, it would return the results I want. I don't want to use file_get_contents because I need to use this function for other API calls that cannot return results by entering the entire link on the address bar. Thanks for helping.

```
<?php
$data_string ='<HotelListRequest><hotelId>A HOTEL</hotelId></HotelListRequest>';

// Tell CURL the URL of the recipient script
$curl_handle = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?minorRev=4&cid=MYID&apiKey=MYAPIKEY&customerSessionId=&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=');

// This section sets various options. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

// Perform the POST and get the data returned by the server.
$result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
// Close the CURL handle
curl_close ($curl_handle);
echo $result; 
?>
```

Comment: check for curl errors - exec() returns boolean FALSE on failure: `if ($result === false) { curl_error($curl_handle); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you put everything into a browser and it works, you're using GET data. Does the service support the use of POST data (which is what you're sending in your example)? Have you tried sending all the data via the CURLOPT_URL?

Also, you'll want to change the data string to

```
"xml=".$data_string
```

and possibly you're other arguments as well (depending on the API).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php :

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. The filetype can be
>   explicitly specified by following the filename with the type in the
>   format ';type=mimetype'. This parameter can either be passed as a
>   urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with
>   the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array,
>   the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP
>   5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix.

So you should modify you $data_string variable content to match the required format.